# Set Value of input type in <td> through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, spring, jsp

This is my spring form code in jsp.

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="itWillRepeat">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                   <tr>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td>item</td>
                      <td>item</td>
                      <td>
                        <form:label path="list[${itemsRow.index}].number">4</form:label>
                        <form:hidden path="list[${itemsRow.index}].number" />
                      </td>
                   </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Browser renders and generates HTML code for 4th `<td>` tag as:

```
<label for="list4.seq">4</label>
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="list[4].seq" id="list4.seq">
```

It shows value in browser as:

```
1  item  item  4
```

I want to change both the values of `<form:label` and `<form:hidden` on any event like onClick through simple JavaScript. I mention just one div with id **itWillRepeat** here. There can be many divs with id **itWillRepeat** because it will come in loop and I want to change values of all `<form:label` in ascending order.

Comment: An Id must be unique in xhtml. Add your index in the id for example id="itWillRepeat-${intemsRow.index}", and now you can create a function to interract with the values of this line.

Comment: "There can be many divs with id itWillRepeat" - that's going to be invalid. Change the `id` to `class` instead.

Comment: Why would you have a `<label>` for a hidden field?

Comment: yep, you should use classes or unique ids for each id1,id2,...,idn.

Comment: Ok. I will use class. Actually there is no id,class for that div. I wrote just for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.onclick = function() {
    var rep = document.getElementById("mainDiv").getElementsByTagName('div');
       for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            //get first label
            var label = rep.getElementsByTagName("label")[0]; 

             label.innerHTML = i+1;
             //get first input
             var hidn = rep.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
              hidn.value = i+1;
         }
};
```

It will get all labels/hidden fields change their values and sort them.

Comment: Did the "itwillrepeat"-selector work? It should be case sensitive ('itWillRepeat')